# Bases for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers

This may be a silly question, but I'm trying to understand bases for $\mathbb{R}^n$. An example in Friedberg's Linear Algebra said that

{($\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$), ($\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}}$)} is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> Ignoring the orthonormal part for now, in general can we take any $n$ vectors (each of length $n$), consisting of any $n$ real numbers as its entries, as a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Because you can "create" a real number as a linear combination of any real numbers, right? Is this line of thinking correct? If not, where did I go wrong in my thinking? Thank you.

Comment: It can't be *any* real numbers.  For instance $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ is not a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ (try to make $(1,0)$ as a linear combination of these -- hint: you can't).  But if you chose numbers at random (with your best random real number generator ) and stuck them in, you'd probably hit a basis.

Comment: think of the columns of a matrix with a non-zero determinant as a basis.

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement isn't true in general. Take, for example, the vectors $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$. They're not linearly independent, so their span is $(k,2k)$. In general, though, in in an $n$-dimensional vector space, any $n$ linearly independent vectors form a basis.

Answer (score 1):

A set of $n$ vectors fails to be a basis if it is linearly dependent, meaning there is some nontrivial linear combination of the vectors that is zero.

In $\mathbb R^2$ this can only happen if one of the vectors is a scalar multiple of the other. For example, the vectors $(1,1),(2,2)$ do not form a basis because 
$$2(1,1)-(2,2)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

> Because you can "create" a real number as a linear combination of any real numbers, right?

No. How can you "create" the real number $2016$ as a linear combination of $0$?